# Passing by value all types but string to a template function

Tags: c++, string, templates, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to define a template function that gets one argument passed by value for all types but `std::string` (and `const char*`).

```
template<typename T>
void foo( T value )
{
    // some code using value
}
```

The `std::string` version should behave exactly as the `template` version, but have its parameter passed by `const&`.

What is the best approach to do what I want without duplicating the body of `foo()`?

The best I was able to think is to wrap the *code using `value`* inside another function, and then call it inside all versions of `foo()` (the `template` version and the `std::string` overload). Is there another way? For example, is it possible to call the `template` version from within the `std::string` overload?

**EDIT**

What I want to know is a good rule of thumb for avoiding code duplication among various specializations and overloads. What is a good pattern to follow? Shall I define a wrapper function for the body and then call that from within all overloads/specializations, or there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid code duplication, the [answer by 101010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410184/678093) can be extended to actually call the template from within the overload:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

template<typename T>
void foo( T value )
{
    std::cout << "inside template" << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(value).name()) << std::endl;
}

void foo(const std::string &value)
{
    std::cout << "inside const string overload" << std::endl;
    foo<const std::string&>(value);
}
int main()
{
    foo(10);
    foo(std::string("hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
inside template
int
inside const string overload
inside template
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >
```

<kbd>[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uwh5gHWYhMIy4LEW)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's what I wanted to achieve. But are you sure the parameter is passed by const ref?

Comment: @PaoloM [yes, it's passed by reference](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DcuNCPK0FkLjAi2n) and [it is const](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0rBHe5bTls6rtBJV)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: provide an overload for `std::string`:

```
void foo( std::string const &value ) {
    // some code using value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a type-trait-like class that will convert `std::string` to `std::string&` and will keep the type for all other types:

```
template<class T>
struct helper {
    typedef T type;
};

template<>
struct helper<std::string> {
    typedef std::string& type; // or const std::string& type if you want
};

template<typename T>
void foo( typename helper<T>::type value, T value2 )
{
    value = value2;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    foo(a, 42);
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // prints 10

    std::string s = "abc";
    foo(s, std::string("def"));
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // prints def
}
```

Full example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96cf78e6c4846172

UPD: as noted by @PiotrSkotnicki, having only one parameter makes type-deduction fail. However, I will keep the answer as it might be helpful in case you indeed have several parameters of type `T` or if you are ok with specifying explicit template parameter to `foo`.

UPD2: To solve the type-deduction problem, you may add another wrapper:

```
template<typename T>
void foo_helper( typename helper<T>::type value )
{
    value = T();
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T& value)
{
    foo_helper<T>(value);
}
```

This still might have some problems, so whether this is applicable to your usecase, is up to you to decide.

Comment: and you add a dummy parameter because `T` is non-deducible otherwise?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, actually I added it just to demonstrate that the behavior is as expected, but yes, this seems to be a problem

Comment: Yes, this is the only answer that try to solve my problem though

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, please also see an edit with another version.

Comment: @Petr why not simply use rvalues?
See my answer.

Comment: @Jonathan, will it pass tests from my first code example?

Comment: @Petr our solutions are different and I think it depends on what the OP is trying to accomplish.
However since it seems that he does not intent to modify the argument in his function(due to wanting to pass a std::string as const reference) I think rvalues provides the better choice.
Even if means that other variables will be passed as a const reference.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, but my solution allows to achieve exactly what he asks for. Actually I even think that if he wanted similar behavior for all lvalues, then he would not mention `std::string` at all.

Comment: @Petr But you won't be able to perform calls such as foo("hello").
Everything will have to be tied to a variable.(at least in your current solution)

Comment: @Jonathan, if you change to `const&` (as OP actually wants; I use non-const reference to be able to clearly demonstrate that the approach works), then you will be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is rvalue signature in C++ 11.

Its as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& value)
{
    std::cout << "was passed by refernece:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value << std::endl;  
    std::cout << value << std::endl;  
}

int main()
{
    std::string text = "hello";
    foo(text);
    foo(1);
}
```

You can either pass the parameter by reference or by value and the rvalue rules will use the appropriate type.

Comment: T&& is actually an universal reference in this case. Hence lvalues and rvalues can bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::enable_if` + `std::is_convertibale`:

```
   template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T,std::string>::value>::type foo( T value )
    {
        // some code using value
    }
```